# calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n!}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate the given expression: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n!}$$

The answer is given as 0 but I can't understand how it evaluates to the value $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0\le \frac{\ln(n)}{n!}\le \frac{n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\text{ , }\forall n\ge2$$
As $n\to \infty,$ $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\to0$ and you have $\frac{\ln n}{n!}\to 0$

Answer (score 5):

Notice for some $n>n_0$, we have

$$ \frac{ \ln n }{n!} < \frac{n}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$

and obviously $\frac{1}{n!} \to 0$ since $e = \sum \frac{1}{n!}$ $\mathbf{converges}$ thus the limit of the nth term better go to $0$

Comment: You did it as I wish to do befoore.